# How to add additianal charges for cash on delivery based on postal codes in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cash-on-delivery

How to add the additional price charges for cash on delivery option selected based on specific postal codes

For Example -: When the customer select the cash on delivery option need to add 50LKR for based on postal code

Ex : postal code 01 - 10500 
     postal code 02 - 10600

If one of these postal code selected with cash on delivery option need to add additional 50LKR to cart total

Comment: XML. You got any shipping extensions currently installed?

Comment: @DominicXigen No!

Comment: Have you considered an extension like this https://webshopapps.com/us/magento-2-extensions/wsa-standalone/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html? Can't say exactly how it will work for you though